# Tile lighting are different colours in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

[This is a screenshot showing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tJWA.png)

[Here is my lighting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yJQ6.png)

As you can see in the first image there is a sample ceiling with lights all having the same material and when I duplicate them they change colour as shown in the first image. What lighting settings should I modify/bake?

Comment: If you are modifying lights' positions or add new ones, you have to rebake the scene

Comment: @Digvijaysinh Gohil Hey thanks for the reply, I know that I have to rebake the scene but I don't know the correct settings that I have to choose. I tried "shadowmask" and weird lightings appear out of nowhere.